# What is the convention for listing different projects on LinkedIn?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, linkedin

I'm trying to improve my LinkedIn profile, so I'm now on the experiences section, I'm trying to list all the project I have done in my current position. But I'm torn between listing them as new experiences like the following :

[image]

Or just add one experience and list the project under that experience, like the following:
[image]

I prefer the first option, but I'm not sure if it is the right one.

Comment: LinkedIn has a section for projects in your profile.

Comment: But I guess that section is just for personal projects.

Comment: No, you associate the project with a role.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention seems to be:

- Add a new experience when your job title changes or you move to a new company/division
- Add projects as bullet points in the description for an experience or as a “project” and associate it with an experience.

This should be consistent with how you present your experience on your resume.